# Connecting PHP and Neo4j

Tags: php, rest, neo4j

I cannot make head nor tail of what should be the simplest usage of neo4j from a php-based webpage and would greatly appreciate some help with the following request. If anyone could provide some example code i would **hugely** appreciate it.

**What is the easiest way to query a local neo4j database api from a php webpage?**

- I have a single, simple php page that receives a submitted form and builds a query from it.
- Using PHP 5.5 in EnterpriseDB ApachePHP
- I do not care how the return results are presented. (At this point, I'll
  take a client-side redirect to the database)
- I do not want to install
  a long string of programs/libraries/updates for this one task.

Answer (score 0):

That is a very general question. You may find the page on [Using Neo4j from PHP](https://neo4j.com/developer/php/) useful.